# Python: Can I grab the specific lines from a large file faster?

Tags: algorithm, python-2.7, bioinformatics, large-files

I have two large files. One of them is an info file(about 270MB and 16,000,000 lines) like this:

```
1101:10003:17729
1101:10003:19979
1101:10003:23319
1101:10003:24972
1101:10003:2539
1101:10003:28242
1101:10003:28804
```

The other is a standard FASTQ format(about 27G and 280,000,000 lines) like this:

```
@ST-E00126:65:H3VJ2CCXX:7:1101:1416:1801 1:N:0:5
NTGCCTGACCGTACCGAGGCTAACCCTAATGAGCTTAATCAAGATGATGCTCGTTATGG
+
AAAFFKKKKKKKKKFKKKKKKKFKKKKAFKKKKKAF7AAFFKFAAFFFKKF7FF<FKK
@ST-E00126:65:H3VJ2CCXX:7:1101:10003:75641:N:0:5
TAAGATAGATAGCCGAGGCTAACCCTAATGAGCTTAATCAAGATGATGCTCGTTATGG
+
AAAFFKKKKKKKKKFKKKKKKKFKKKKAFKKKKKAF7AAFFKFAAFFFKKF7FF<FKK
```

The FASTQ file uses four lines per sequence. Line 1 begins with a '@' character and is followed by a sequence identifie. For each sequence,this part of the Line 1 is unique.

```
1101:1416:1801 and 1101:10003:75641
```

And I want to grab the Line 1 and the next three lines from the FASTQ file according to the info file. Here is my code:

```
import gzip
import re

count = 0
with open('info_path') as info, open('grab_path','w') as grab:
        for i in info:
                sample = i.strip()
                with gzip.open('fq_path') as fq:
                        for j in fq:
                                count += 1
                                if count%4 == 1:
                                        line = j.strip()
                                        m = re.search(sample,j)
                                        if m != None:
                                                grab.writelines(line+'\n'+fq.next()+fq.next()+fq.next())
                                                count = 0
                                                break
```

And it works, but because both of these two files have millions of lines, it's inefficient(running one day only get 20,000 lines).

UPDATE at July 6th:

I find that the info file can be read into the memory(thank @tobias_k for reminding me), so I creat a dictionary that the keys are info lines and the values are all 0. After that, I read the FASTQ file every 4 line, use the identifier part as the key,if the value is 0 then return the 4 lines. Here is my code:

```
import gzip

dic = {}
with open('info_path') as info:
        for i in info:
                sample = i.strip()
                dic[sample] = 0
with gzip.open('fq_path') as fq, open('grap_path',"w") as grab:
        for j in fq:
                if j[:10] == '@ST-E00126':
                        line = j.split(':')
                        match = line[4] +':'+line[5]+':'+line[6][:-2]
                        if dic.get(match) == 0:
                                grab.writelines(j+fq.next()+fq.next()+fq.next())
```

This way is much faster, it takes 20mins to get all the matched lines(about 64,000,000 lines). And I have thought about sorting the FASTQ file first by external sort. Splitting the file that can be read into the memory is ok, my trouble is how to keep the next three lines following the indentifier line while sorting. The Google's answer is to linear these four lines first, but it will take 40mins to do so.

Anyway thanks for your help.

Comment: Side note: you can do `with open('info_path') as info, open('grab_path', 'w') as grab:`

Comment: Can you transform the second file to an in-memory dictionary? Or maybe a database?

Comment: @zlc1994, anyway you can sort the second file and probably create some index into positions in it...

Answer (score 2):

You can sort both files by the identifier (the `1101:1416:1801`) part. Even if files do not fit into memory, you can use [external sorting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/External_sorting).

After this, you can apply a simple merge-like strategy: read both files together and do the matching in the meantime. Something like this (pseudocode):

```
entry1 = readFromFile1()
entry2 = readFromFile2()
while (none of the files ended)
    if (entry1.id == entry2.id)
        record match
    else if (entry1.id < entry2.id)
        entry1 = readFromFile1()
    else 
        entry2 = readFromFile2()
```

This way `entry1.id` and `entry2.id` are always close to each other and you will not miss any matches. At the same time, this approach requires iterating over each file once.